# Derivative of a coordinate of a vector w.r.t. its norm

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Let $x \in \mathbb R^n$ and $\|x\| = \sqrt{x_1^2 + \dots + x_n^2}$ the usual euclidean norm. Does it make sense to consider the derivative of a coordinate w.r.t. the norm, i.e. can I define
$$ \dfrac{\partial x_1}{\partial \|x\|} $$
and how should I calculate? Also if I fix another point $y \in \mathbb R^n$, does it makes sense to calculate
$$\dfrac{\partial \| x- y\|}{\partial \|x\|} \quad ?$$

Comment: Go into spherical coordinates and take derivative by $r$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

In spherical coordinates:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
\| \mathbf{x}\| = r \\
x_1 = r \text{cos}(\phi_1) \\
x_2 = r \text{sin}(\phi_1)\text{cos}(\phi_2) \\
x_2 = r \text{sin}(\phi_1)\text{sin}(\phi_2)\text{cos}(\phi_3) \\
\vdots \\
x_{n-1} =  r \text{sin}(\phi_1)\cdots \text{sin}(\phi_{n-2})\text{cos}(\phi_{n-1}) \\
x_{n} =  r \text{sin}(\phi_1)\cdots \text{sin}(\phi_{n-2})\text{sin}(\phi_{n-1}), \\
\end{array}
\end{equation}
where $\phi_1, \phi_2, \ldots, \phi_n$ are the angular coordinates and $r$ the radius of the hypersphere.